# Short-circuited ethernet wiring? Cable tester loop

Tags: connection, ethernet

Ethernet at the place I rent was dead, and since I noticed the wire was terminated in "reverse" 568 B standard, I bought crimper and cable tester to fix it.
However, there is still NO connection between the router and room ends. I know I terminated it correctly, because I tested some cables I practised on and they tested fine.
What is really strange is that signal tester, when connected to room end only, gives signals on 5 wires without the other end being connected to the remote part...
When I plug in just one end of a free wire to the tester, it doesn't light up.
Does it mean the wire is short-circuited somewhere, and the tester sends signal back to itself?
Help, my landlord is  lazy  and I can't get him to fix it for 3 months now, can it be something I can fix myself?

Comment: Tell your landlord the broken Ethernet cable has started a large electrical fire that's threatening to burn the place to the ground.  And if necessary, start one.  Bet he comes quick.

Comment: Check whether the cable is crimped on the both end of the cable

Comment: `I know I terminated it correctly, because I tested some cables I practised on and they tested fine` - Testing some cables that aren't actually the problematic cable is not in fact a validation that the problematic cable is terminated correctly, regardless of your "crimping" skills.

Comment: Without knowing what is at the other end of the cable, it is pretty impossible to give an answer. Is the other end patched to anything useful/working?